# Image texture GLCM (mean_Envi)

Tags: r, textures, glcm

I am running a Image texture measures from grey-level co-occurrence matrices (GLCM) on Landsat bands using the glcm package in R and I would like to know what is the difference between mean' and 'mean_ENVI' / 'variance' and 'variance_ENVI'.

It seems to be a basic question but I couldn't find a good explanation for that.

```
library(glcm)

Feb2014_B2 <-raster ("Feb2014_band2x.tif")

Feb2014.B2.textures3x3 <- glcm(Feb2014_B2, window = c(3, 3), shift = c(1, 1),   
statistics = c("mean", "mean_ENVI", "variance", "variance_ENVI",  
"homogeneity", "contrast", "dissimilarity", "entropy", "second_moment", 
"correlation"), na_opt="any", na_val=NA)
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example (data and code) that shows what are we talking about?

Comment: Roman Luštrik I just updated my question with an example. Thanks

Comment: Reference section of `glcm` function cites 4 references. Have you read them to see if they list anything useful?

Answer (score 7):

I am the author of the R glcm package. The difference between mean and mean_ENVI and between variance and variance_ENVI has to do with how the mean is calculated. The mean and variance in the glcm package are implemented as in the original [Haralick publication](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfpNrxkKbMAhXERCYKHdn3DkkQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fharalick.org%2Fjournals%2FTexturalFeatures.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFKXoMgiT_A5UHAWoi1l4i1n0eaQA&sig2=vHhSKTvJjXQjd35oX5h-7Q). The mean and variance in ENVI are implemented differently. ENVI calculates the mean as a simple mean of the pixel values within the given window size – so the ENVI mean is not a texture measure at all, but simply a smoothed version of your original image. I implemented it in my package to make it possible to reproduce ENVI results in R.

The formulas I use are as in Haralick. Right now the only way to see them is in the C++ code (https://github.com/azvoleff/glcm/blob/master/src/calc_texture.cpp). I will get these into the R docs eventually, but haven't yet had time to throw them into the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the difference between both is clear. It would be really useful if this information is written in the R docs.

Comment: Does this also refer to the other co-occurence measures in ENVI? I found significant differences between ENVI results and GLCM properties (calculated from https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycomatrix

Comment: My results (using the formulas as in the references given in the R GLCM package) match the results from ENVI for the other texture measures - just not for the mean. Not sure how they compare with scikit though - would be curious to know which measures vary.